# Vue.js random image not showing

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Anyone have an idea to why this isn't working for me? I'm running a vue-cli build. I don't get any errors, but the image isn't showing. I'm new to vue.js so the solution is most likely pretty simple. Any help is greatly appreciated...

```
<template>
  <section>
    <img :src="selectedImage" />
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: {
    images: [
      'http://via.placeholder.com/200x140',
      'http://via.placeholder.com/200x100'
    ],
    selectedImage: ''
  },
  created () {
    const idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.images.length)
    this.selectedImage = this.images[idx]
  }
}
</script>
```

This is my main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
import messages from './components/locale'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(VueI18n)

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'en',
  messages
})

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App },
  i18n
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `data` should be a function that returns an object.

```
<template>
  <section>
    <img :src="selectedImage" />
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      images: [
        'http://via.placeholder.com/200x140',
        'http://via.placeholder.com/200x100'
      ],
      selectedImage: ''
    }
  },
  created () {
    const idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.images.length)
    this.selectedImage = this.images[idx]
  }
}
</script>
```

Here's an explanation why data must be function: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

Basically, it is dictated by design that `data` must be a function that returns an object, to avoid cross referencing JavaScript objects.

Comment: Why should it be a function in this case?

Comment: Check it out: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function. Added an edit.

Comment: Thanks a million @Manish